# Selecting the active layer

Tags: python, layers

Every time I create a script to create text it adds the text into layer 1, when in fact I am working in layer 3. I realize the "True" relates to layer 1, so I possibly require a script in its place.?

```
bpy.ops.object.text_add(
        radius=3, 
        view_align=True,
        enter_editmode=False,  
        layers=(True, False, False, False, 
                False, False, False, False,
                False, False, False, False, 
                False, False, False, False,
                False, False, False, False))

bpy.ops.transform.translate(
        value=(0, 0, 2), 
        constraint_axis=(False, False, True), 
        constraint_orientation='LOCAL',
        mirror=False,
        proportional='DISABLED',
        proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH',
        proportional_size=1)
```

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34319/how-to-add-object-to-a-specific-layer-with-python

Comment: I have mistakenly killed my 2.79 version with a lib update... so I can't test right now. Try `bpy.ops.object.text_add()` and see which layer it adds it to (given what layer you are on) or use `layers = bpy.context.scene.layers` to put the object on the same layers as the current scene. This could be the default...IIRC

Comment: Unfortunately it still throws the text into layer 1..